# MariaDB service doesn't start

Tags: centos, service, mariadb

I tried to restart it but still doesn't. I've been seeing some post but don't is the same problem. The server is CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

The output o systemctl status mariadb is:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-05-02 05:54:22 -05; 7min ago
Process: 26120 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 02 05:54:22 srv01web-taws systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
May 02 05:54:22 srv01web-taws systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 02 05:54:22 srv01web-taws systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
May 02 05:54:22 srv01web-taws systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
May 02 05:54:22 srv01web-taws systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

The output when I try restart it is:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The output of 'journalctl -xe' is:

```
-- Unit user-48.slice has finished shutting down.
May 02 06:09:02 srv01web-taws systemd[1]: Stopping User Slice of apache.
-- Subject: Unit user-48.slice has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit user-48.slice has begun shutting down.
May 02 06:10:01 srv01web-taws systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of apache.
-- Subject: Unit user-48.slice has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit user-48.slice has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
May 02 06:10:01 srv01web-taws systemd[1]: Starting User Slice of apache.
-- Subject: Unit user-48.slice has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit user-48.slice has begun starting up.
May 02 06:10:01 srv01web-taws systemd[1]: Started Session 248209 of user apache.
-- Subject: Unit session-248209.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-248209.scope has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
May 02 06:10:01 srv01web-taws systemd[1]: Starting Session 248209 of user apache.
-- Subject: Unit session-248209.scope has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-248209.scope has begun starting up.
May 02 06:10:01 srv01web-taws CROND[27027]: (apache) CMD (/usr/bin/php  /var/www/html/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php >/dev/null)
May 02 06:10:03 srv01web-taws systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of apache.
-- Subject: Unit user-48.slice has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit user-48.slice has finished shutting down.
May 02 06:10:03 srv01web-taws systemd[1]: Stopping User Slice of apache.
-- Subject: Unit user-48.slice has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit user-48.slice has begun shutting down.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided it is not clear what is the root cause of the problem. You can see in the output of `systemctl status mariadb` that the command `/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir` failed when starting the service.

I guess in most cases this is related to permission problems and/or misconfigured paths in the mariadb config.

For further debugging I would execute the `/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir` manually with the user for mariadb as defined in the unit file. You can use `systemctl show mariadb` to get the correct user name. Also check the mariadb config for wrong paths (the path for the actual db files as well as the log path)

Comment: I ran `/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir` and this was the output

Database MariaDB is not initialized, but the directory /var/lib/mysql is not empty, so initialization cannot be done.
Make sure the /var/lib/mysql is empty before running mariadb-prepare-db-dir.

Comment: One thing more, I think that the error began when I tried by mistake install mysql when MariaDB was already running. I was reading and I tried uninstalling MariaDB and all packages of MySQL but mariadb.service still doesn't work, any suggestion?

Comment: If you uninstall a database package the directory holding the actual data is usually not deleted. It sounds like that you don't have any data in the database. If that is the case you could delete the files in `/var/lib/mysql` and mariadb should startup just fine.